# Rails has many through params in create action problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a csv import function that is creating many cardrequests for each id in the csv. I have a has many through relationship for the cardholdergroup model. How do I tell this create action to create the records and set the cardholdergroup_ids: [] param on create?

```
  CSV.foreach(file_path) do |row|
   @cardrequest = Cardrequest.create(empid: row[0], 
   startdate: cardrequest_params[:startdate], 
   enddate: cardrequest_params[:enddate], user_id: current_user.id, 
   cardholdergroup_ids: cardrequest_params[cardholdergroup_ids: []
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be `cardrequest_params[:cardholdergroup_ids]`

Comment: That was it. Thanks!